# How to setup retention for CloudWatch log in CloudFormation YAML template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

In the console it's like super easy. But I just couldn't find how to do in the YAML template for CloudFormation?

Answer (score 3):

The [AWS::Logs::LogGroup - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html) documentation shows:

```
myLogGroup: 
  Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
  Properties: 
    RetentionInDays: 7
```

> `RetentionInDays`
>
> The number of days log events are kept in CloudWatch Logs. When a log event expires, CloudWatch Logs automatically deletes it.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that one too. Thanks